# How to correctly use and install Axios

Tags: typescript, axios

I have the following configuration for my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{

  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "ES6",
    //"strict": true,
    "types": [ "node", "bootstrap", "jquery", "axios"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types", // Default path to search typings.
      "./lib/types" // Directory of typings that located by Libman.
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "../wwwroot/assets/js/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I added into my types array axios after I install the following:

```
npm i axios --global
npm install --save-dev @types/axios
```

When I open my `node_modules` -> `@types` -> `axios` I see the following:

[image]

So in this case I don't see a `/dist` folder

Then in my TypeScript file I have the following code:

[image]

And after compiling I get of course the following error:

```
error TS2304: Build:Cannot find name 'axios'.
```

Any clue how to make it work? I don't want to use the `import` word in my TS file.

Comment: You only need globally scoped types in the `types` array. Axios isn't one of those, you need to import it. Also it doesn't need the separate types package, they're bundled.

Comment: @jonrsharpe if I import it I can build without issue but in the browser console I get an error Failed to resolve module specifier "axios". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". Of course I had to add to my script reference the type=module 

<script type="module" src="~/assets/js/test.js"></script>

But by some reason once in browser it cant find the library or package

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to use the import word in my TS file.

Why do you not want to import it in your TS file?

Being able to set dependencies for the project in the `package.json` file instead of globally is exactly what npm is designed for. Otherwise anyone who would use your code would need to manually install axois globally before they could run it.

I think that what you're asking for isn't possible. The correct way to install and use axois is to add it to your project's `package.json`, and use `import` to access it from your TS file:

```
npm install axios
```

```
import axios from 'axios';

await axios.get(...);
```

Comment: Hi, if I import by some reason when I see my app in browser I get a Failed to resolve module specifier "axios". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".  

And that's because the client can't find the library. That happened to me also for bootstrap and jquery in TS, that's why I added those in the type array in tsconfig

Comment: If you're loading it in the browser, you probably need to use a bundler like webpack to create a JS file containing your typescript code and these dependencies (axios, bootstrap, etc)